# How can i update many to many relations in grails?

Tags: grails, grails-orm, scaffolding

I am doing a website with grails , I have used scaffoling plugin to make a CMS.
I have a domain class activity that has 4 many-to-many relations and this class is the owner of all the relations. So when I edit a activity from my CMS, I have this:

```
http-bio-8080-exec-2] ERROR errors.GrailsExceptionResolver  - MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException occurred when processing request: [POST] /KurbanaProject/actividad/update/1
Duplicate entry '1-2' for key 'PRIMARY'. Stacktrace follows:
Message: Duplicate entry '1-2' for key 'PRIMARY
```

How can I update many to many relations?

thanks

Comment: Without knowing what your Domain model looks like, or the code you are using to persist the changes we won't be able to assist you. Add your domain classes and any relevant (non-scaffolded) controller code. Also, include your version of Grails.

Comment: I have faced same problem, it seems completely random, for some records, it is updated, deleted, but for some others exception happened. The basic mode is class NotificationGroup {
    String name
    static hasMany = [  externalMedia : ExternalMedia ]
 }        class ExternalMedia {
    String email
    static hasMany = [ notifGroup : NotificationGroup ]
    static belongsTo = [ NotificationGroup ] 
 }

Comment: I have the solution , the problem was that hibernate proxy was caching the middle table in many to many relation so I added in my model 
static mapping{ <relation> lazy : false


}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the solution , the problem was that hibernate proxy was caching the middle table in many to many relation so I added in my model

```
static mapping {
    relation lazy: false
}
```